# First category $ \cup_{n}\cap_{m}\cup_{k}A_{n,m,k} $

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $X$ be a topological space and let us consider nowhere dense subsets $(A_{n,m,k})_{n,m,k \ge 1}$. Is it true that
$$
\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\bigcap_{m\ge 1}\bigcup_{k\ge 1}A_{n,m,k}
$$
is of first category?

Comment: Yes: it is contained in $\bigcup_n \bigcup_k A_{n,1,k}$.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti . Best 1-liner I've seen this week.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner union gives us sets of first category, and the intersection only makes them smaller, so all sets $\bigcap_{m\ge 1}\bigcup_{k\ge 1}A_{n,m,k}$ are also of first category, and so their union is too.

Note that this works in any $\sigma$-ideal.